# Need help to write right parsing option

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, parsing

I need to parse text file which looks like this:

```
key : 123             
anotherKey : qwer                

oneMoreKey :         
somestring,        
somestring
```

There are a lot of this type of strings, they are generated automatically by server, so I don't know how much of them will receive parser

I have solved parsing of foo : bar like this:

```
def main():
    data = {}
    file = open('file.txt')  # opening log file
    for line in file:
        if re.match(r'^\s*$', line):
            pass
        else:
            line = line.split(':')

        key = line[0].strip() 
        if len(line) == 2: # this is a workaround for lines like "foo :\n
            value = line[1].strip()
        else:
            value = 'none'

        if key in data:
            pass
        else:
            data[key] = value
```

I need to get all data in json like

```
{
    key : 123,
    anotherKey : qwer,
    oneMoreKey : [somestring, somestring]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sth. like this?

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'^(?P<key>\w+)\s:(?P<value>.+?)(?=^\w+\s*:|\Z)', re.S | re.M)

junk = """key : 123             
anotherKey : qwer                
foo : bar, zxc
oneMoreKey :         
somestring,        
somestring         


"""


def match(m):
    values = [val for value in re.split(r', *[\n\r]+', m) for val in [value.strip()] if val]
    return values if len(values) > 1 else m.strip()

d = {m.group('key'): match(m.group('value')) for m in rx.finditer(junk)}
print(d)
```

This yields

```
{'key': '123', 'anotherKey': 'qwer', 'foo': 'bar, zxc', 'oneMoreKey': ['somestring', 'somestring']}
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/83PFeh/1).

Comment: Can You modify it to work with strings like "foo : bar, zxc" and IPv4 addresses? It now breaks on this strings if I am receiving them

Comment: @ExtremumMax: Updated, see the answer.